# I want to change json format to table format

Tags: python, json, arraylist

I want to change json format to tabular format using python.
dict and list are used in nesting.

### Currently

> {'tables': [{'name': 'PrimaryResult', 'columns': [{'name': 'TimeGenerated', 'type': 'datetime'}, {'name': 'OperationName', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'Category', 'type': 'string'}], 'rows': [['2021-08-24T04:08:01.966Z', 'Restore application', 'ApplicationManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:52:22.14Z', 'Bulk create users - started (bulk)', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:52:22.671Z', 'Bulk create users - finished (bulk)', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:52:22.471Z', 'Add user', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:52:22.501Z', 'Add user', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:52:22.594Z', 'Add user', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:52:22.513Z', 'Add user', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:54:48.482Z', 'Enable Strong Authentication', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:54:48.487Z', 'Update user', 'UserManagement'], ['2021-08-24T06:54:33.391Z', 'Enable Strong Authentication', 'UserManagement']]}]}

### Table

headers: tables | TimeGenerated | OperationName | Category

eg: PrimaryResult, 2021-08-24T04:08:01.966Z, Restore application, ApplicationManagement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quick and straightforward solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Open JSON file
with open('{your_file_path}') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Create dataframe
pd_data = data['tables'][0]['rows']
pd_columns = [v['name'] for k, v in enumerate(data['tables'][0]['columns'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd_data, columns=pd_columns)
```

You may export the dataframe to various table format provided by pandas.

Comment: oh.....Thank you!!! It seems that the dict type and the json file are different.
It was successful by creating a file in the json file type.